# Managing and customizing cursors with GWT, CSS

Tags: css, gwt, widget, mouse-cursor

I want to be able to limit the cursor within 30px to left, right, top and bottom within click point.
Basically, I have a custom drag and drop implemented with GWT, and while users are dragging
the div cursor should be around the div itself (currently cursor could be anywhere while draggging). 
I also want to be able to change the cursor to "hand icon" when the dragging starts.

In general what is a best way to manage cursors with GWT?
I don't know if this is doable but any example would be a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its doable. If you limit the size of the immediate next panel to rootpanel, I believe the pointer can't escape beyond the boundary...